# Struts 2 how to prevent nullpointerexceptions in action with validate

Tags: jsp, struts2

I just started working with my first Struts 2 project and I'm currently working with a registration-action.

The registration is going fine except when you access `Register.action` directly from the url, when you do that the class-variables isn't instantiated (for example `String password`) and I get nullpointer-exceptions when using them. `Register.action` is the action that processes the `register.jsp` form.

Is there a way to stop users from accessing `Register.action` without coming from `register.jsp`? 
Or do I need to nullcheck everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't be accessing a JSP page directly, except under rare circumstances, when using an MVC framework: all activity should take place through an action.

Second, as Aleksandr says, validation should be handled through the framework, either through XML, annotation, or Java-based means. In this case, accessing the processing action directly should result in a validation failure, since the username/password fields are required.

Once validation fails (depending on your configuration, but for example) the framework will forward to the `"input"` result, likely the registration JSP page.

Comment: How to avoid that an user accesses an .jsp directly and causes an exception? For example if I use <s:radio /> tag, then I need to have an action before or I will get an exception. How do I avoid that?

Comment: @JohanS Normally JSP pages are put under `WEB-INF` to avoid direct client access.

Comment: @JohanS I don't recall what is returned, but they don't get the JSP page.

Answer (score 3):

You can use validation feature to validate required variables http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/validation.html.